# Combine a parametric plot and a regular plot into one plot

Tags: plotting

I have the following :

```
ODE = 2.*10^(-6)/R[t]^2 + 4053/(40 R[t]) + (4.008*10^(-6) R'[t]/
  R[t]^2 + (3 R'[t]^2)/(2 R[t]) + R''[t];

s = NDSolve[{ODE== 0, R'[0] == 0, R[0] == R0}, R, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxSteps -> 20000, AccuracyGoal -> 15, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 15];

fig1 = Plot[R[t] /. s, {t, 0, 0.001}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "R(t)"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.001}, {0, 0.01}}]
```

and I also have

```
t3 = (1.5*^-8 τ)/(1. + 1.5*^-10 τ^2)^(1/3) - 
  5.*^-9 τ Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 3/2, -1.52*^-10 τ^2];

R3 = 0.01/(1 + 1.5*^-10 τ^2)^(1/3);

fig2 = ParametricPlot[{t3, R3}, {τ, 0, 10000}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "R(t)"}]
```

How can I plot both figures on the same plot. I need to see the differences between the two curves.

Comment: Does `Show[fig1, fig2]` not work?

Comment: So I can't use your code, there are a couple of formatting errors, with an unmatched parentheses.  There's also an undefined constant, `R0`.  But to your question, look at `Show`

Comment: As a side note, to check for the quality of a numerical solution it's helpful to plot the difference between the analytical and the numerical solution; that is more informative then the plots on top of each other, I find.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what we want , to see the difference between the exact solution involving 2F1 and the numerical solution obtained.

Answer (score 2):

I have corrected your code in ODE and NDSolve. In addition, I have R0 with 0.01 Ohm adopted.

```
ODE = 
  2.*10^(-6)/R[t]^2 + 4053/(40 R[t]) + 4.008*10^(-6) R'[t]/R[t]^2 + 
    3 R'[t]^2/(2 R[t]) + R''[t];
s = 
  First @ 
    NDSolve[{ODE == 0, R'[0] == 0, R[0] == R0} /. R0 -> 0.01,R, 
    {t, 0, 0.0001}];
fig1 = Plot[R[t] /. s, {t, 0, 0.0001}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "R(t)"}];

t3 = 
  (1.5*^-8 τ)/(1.` + 1.5*^-10 τ^2)^(1/3) -
    5.*^-9 τ Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 3/2, -1.52`*^-10 τ^2];
R3 = 0.01/(1 + 1.5*^-10 τ^2)^(1/3); 
fig2 = 
  ParametricPlot[{t3, R3}, {τ, 0, 10000}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "R(t)"}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}];

Show[fig1,fig2]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot last line  is Show[fig1,fig2]